# Identifying map author?

Tags: cartography

I need to know author of this map in order to quote its authors in a book.

[image: macaronesia region]

Comment: Can you give us a clue as to where you found it?

Comment: The purpose of GIS SE  is to compile answers to GIS questions. There is no reason to believe this *is* a GIS question. You haven't provided a lineage or chain of custody of how you obtained the image, making this more of a trivia exercise, in effect, soliciting guesses in a question/answer forum. I do thank you for taking the Tour, but it does state that you should ask `Specific questions concerning geographic information systems and science`, and this question does not qualify. A more discussion-oriented site might help, if you provide more information.

Answer (score 4):

A Google search for `"chart of the cape verd isles"` suggests the cartographer is someone called Alexander HOGG.

You seem to only have part of the original map sheet which apparently was published in Moore's New & Complete Collection of Voyages and Travels in 1785

ref: https://www.antiquemaps.org.uk/i/8151-Various-Charts-of-Is